# Запись в файл ввода с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

Создаю бинарный файл.Хочу ввести строку с клавиатуры и поместить в файл. Считывается только первое слово до пробела. Как считывать все предложение?

```
int main()
{

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[256] = "";
    FILE * name;
    name = fopen("name.bin", "wb");
    cout << "Вводим строку:";
    cin >> str;
    fwrite(&str,sizeof(str),256,name);
    fclose(name);
    name = fopen("name.bin", "rb");
    fread(&str, sizeof(str), 256, name);
    cout << str;
    fclose(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Используйте gets/cin.getline

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
cout << "Вводим строку:";
cin.getline(str,256);
```

Только вот тут

```
fwrite(&str,sizeof(str),256,name);
fread(&str, sizeof(str), 256, name);
```

вы записываете и читаете несколько, гм... больше, чем хотелось :)

Пишите просто:

```
fwrite(str,sizeof(str),1,name);
fread(str, sizeof(str),1,name);
```

Хотя лично я бы делал так:

```
int len = strlen(str)+1;
fwrite(&len,sizeof(len),1,name);
fwrite(str,len,1,name);
```

и

```
fread(&len,sizeof(len),1,name);
fread(str,len,1,name);
```

Comment: Вы бы не могли написать полностью текст программы добавление строки в файл, а не фрагментами. У меня все равно вводится только первое слово

Comment: Только при условии, что я ее и сдаю преподу, и оценку получаю тоже я :)

Comment: Это не для препода. Я сам пытаюсь разобраться с файлами в с++. Который день. Испробовал все методы. Не могу с этим справиться.Может у нас получится списаться напрямую вконтакте. Если не трудно,я бы мог обращаться с вопросами в трудную минуту)
https://vk.com/plysenko_maks Пожалуйста, если не трудно - напишите)

Comment: Ну так замените свои строки строками из ответа. Вместо `cin>>str` - как я написал, в fwrite/fread 256 замените на 1 - уже начнет работать.

Comment: Большое спасибо) Извините за неудобства

Comment: Да нет вопросов :) Приходите еще, только помните, что тут предпочитают отвечать на вопросы, над которыми видна работа автора...

Comment: Кстати, если ответ вас устроил  - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый...